# Matrix Representation of Normal Operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$, and take $T \in \mathcal L(V)$.  Suppose that $\beta$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$.  It can be shown that:
$$TT{}^* = T{}^*T \, \, \longleftrightarrow \, \, [T]{}_\beta [T]{}_\beta{}^* = [T]{}_\beta{}^* [T]{}_\beta$$

That is because we can write:
\begin{align*}
[TT{}^*]{}_\beta & = [T]{}_\beta [T{}^*]{}_\beta = [T]{}_\beta [T]{}_\beta{}^* \\
[T{}^*T]{}_\beta & = [T{}^*]{}_\beta [T]{}_\beta = [T]{}_\beta{}^* [T]{}_\beta
\end{align*}

If $X$ is not an orthonormal basis, it is possible that $[T{}^*]{}_X \ne [T]{}_X{}^*$.  Thus, if the underlying basis is not orthonormal, the above characterization $\textbf{MAY NOT}$ hold.

I felt this is a little strange because the definition of normality does not mention any basis.  See an example below:

> [image: Friedberg, et al, Linear Algebra, 2nd Edition]

Yet, in the matrix representation of the operator, the choice of our basis matters.  Is this going to cause an error?  Perhaps it somehow works out that:
$$[T]{}_X [T]{}_X{}^* = [T]{}_X{}^* [T]{}_X$$
leading me to erroneously conclude that $TT{}^* = T{}^*T$?

Comment: Are you confusing the operator with its matrix?

Comment: I think the question is why a property for an operator depends on our choice of the basis?  For example, when I define $\det T$, the choice of my basis is not relevant because $$\det [T]{}_X = \det [Q]{}^{-1} \det [T]{}_Y \det[Q] = \det [T]{}_Y \det [Q]{}^{-1} \det[Q] = \det [T]{}_Y$$  Maybe I am reading too much into this ....